# compare hash table in emacs lisp?

Tags: elisp, hashtable

It seems that `equal` can not compare hash table properly. Here is an exmaple

```
(defun hash-alist (alist)
  "Convert association list to a hash table and return it."
  (let ((my-hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (dolist (entry alist)
      (puthash (car entry) (cdr entry) my-hash))
    my-hash))
(setq a '((?a . 1) (?b . 2)))
(setq b (hash-alist a))
(setq c (hash-alist a))
(equal b c)
```

The last line of code returns `nil`. Is there any other function to compare two hash tables?

Comment: I don't know of anything standard. You could find/implement some library that does a set minus operation. Then the hashes are equal if the result of set minus has length 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since there is no function builtin Emacs to do this. I wrote it just in case people be interested:

```
(defun hash-equal (hash1 hash2)
  "Compare two hash tables to see whether they are equal."
  (and (= (hash-table-count hash1)
          (hash-table-count hash2))
       (catch 'flag (maphash (lambda (x y)
                               (or (equal (gethash x hash2) y)
                                   (throw 'flag nil)))
                             hash1)
              (throw 'flag t))))
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Since 2013 there is a modern hash-table library for Emacs: [**`ht`**](https://github.com/Wilfred/ht.el). It provides a feature-rich API, similar to [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) for lists and trees, [**`s`**](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) for strings, [**`f`**](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) for files.

Installing third-party libraries in Emacs 24 is really simple, read **`ht`** [installation instructions](https://github.com/Wilfred/ht.el#installation).

There is no built-in equality function in **`ht`**, so we still have to write our own function. There are two ways I think up of testing 2 hash-tables for equality:

```
(defun ht-equal-1 (t1 t2)
  (equal (ht-items t1) (ht-items t2)))

(defun ht-equal-2 (t1 t2)
  (and (= (ht-size t1)
          (ht-size t2))
       (ht-map (lambda (k v) (equal (ht-get t1 k) v))
               t2)))
```

They should both be quick for small hash-tables, but we aren't sure which one is faster for bigger hash-tables, so let's create a relatively big hash-tables by using [`ht<-plist`](https://github.com/Wilfred/ht.el#converting-to-a-hash-table):

```
(setq foo-table-1 (ht<-plist (number-sequence 1 10000) 'equal))
(setq foo-table-2 (ht<-plist (number-sequence 1 10000) 'equal))
```

There is a great Elisp function [`benchmark-run`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html) that can run a function or an Elisp expression multiple times and then report the time it took. Let's run our 2 functions, each comparing 2 hash-tables we just created:

```
(benchmark-run 1000 (ht-equal-1 foo-table-1 foo-table-2))
;; => (5.36585361 4 0.6110091979999996)
(benchmark-run 1000 (ht-equal-2 foo-table-1 foo-table-2))
;; => (3.708278817 0 0.0)
```

It seems `ht-equal-2` runs faster, so you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with the combination of the `hash-table-count`, `maphash`, and `gethash` functions you could roll your own hash table equality test easily enough.